Maui Prism Tabbed Page Title Setting
I'm building out an app in Maui using Prism. I have a tabbed page and I want to programmatically change the title of both the tabs and the parent/master tabbed page separately.
For example, I want the master tabbed page to say something like "Customer Setup" and then want the first tab to initialize and rename itself to something like "Bizspeed Inc. Info" and renames the master tabbed page to something like "Bizspeed Inc. Setup" once it initializes and looks up the customer. Right now it seems as though if I bind the tabbedpage title to Title, that setting Title in the code sets the title for both the tab and the master page.
enter image description here
I tried binding the master page title to a field called Title that is set programmatically. The challenge is that this is setting both the master page Title and the tab page Title.
Tabbed Page XAML Code:
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="goRoamSalesSupport.Views.CustomerOnboardingPage"
            Title="Customer Info">
  
  <TabbedPage.Children>
    <views:CustomerOnboardingInfoPage Title="Info" />
    <views:CustomerOnboardingSettingsPage Title="Settings"/>
  </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>

Navigation to the tabbed page:
 await navigationService
 .CreateBuilder()
 .AddParameter("custRefId", customer.CustomerRefId).AddTabbedSegment(b =>
     b.CreateTab("CustomerOnboardingInfoPage").CreateTab("CustomerOnboardingSettingsPage"))
 .NavigateAsync(async (exc) =>
     {
         await userDialogs.AlertAsync($"Could not navigate to Customer Setup Page: {exc.Message}", "Navigation Error");
         userDialogs.HideLoading();
     }
 );


Please include some relevant code in your post.
